# what is the purpose of 'if submit in request.params'

Tags: pyramid

I've seen this code in some examples and it isn't true when I submit a form. So what is it?

```
if 'submit' in request.POST:
  # blah
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this check is to tell whether the form is being submitted (POST) or just being displayed (GET) - for the reasons of validation etc. it is often done from the same view function, even though Pyramid allows to register a separate view function for GET and POST requests.

The 'submit' parameter comes from the `name` attribute of the submit button:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save your changes" />
</form>
```

To be honest, I dislike this approach as it relies on sending an otherwise useless name/value pair in a rather obscure manner (you've got confused, right?).

As an alternative you may try the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # save the data
else:
    # simply display the form
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see all of your request body using

```
print request.params
#or just post request
print request.POST
```

if isn't true when you submit a form,
 make sure you make a right request(`post`) or try have a attribute `name=submit` at your submit button.